# Laravel: how to show data to create chart in JavaScript file?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show on the chart the number of new students registered and the number of online students per month. I got the data but I don't know how to transfer data into js file to draw that chart.

Here is js file.

```
var chart = document.getElementById('products-sales');
let newStudent = $("#monthNewStudent").val();
let onlStudent = $("#monthOnline").val();
var newStudentArr = newStudent.split(",");
var onlStudentArr = onlStudent.split(",");
let arrNew = JSON.parse(newStudentArr);
let arrOnl = JSON.parse(onlStudentArr);

arrData  = [];
for (var i in arrNew) {
   arrData.push({
      month:i,
      newStudent: arrNew[i],
      onlStudent: arrOnl[i]
   });
}

var months = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'products-sales',
        data: [{
            month: '2017-01',
            newstudent: 0,
            online: 0,
        }],
        xkey: 'month',
        ykeys: ['newstudent', 'online'],
        labels: ['Học viên mới', 'Học viên online'],
        xLabelFormat: function(x) { // <--- x.getMonth() returns valid index
            var month = months[x.getMonth()];
            return month;
        },
        dateFormat: function(x) {
            var month = months[new Date(x).getMonth()];
            return month;
        },
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        ymax: 300,
        resize: true,
        pointSize: 0,
        pointStrokeColors:['#00B5B8', '#FA8E57', '#F25E75'],
        smooth: true,
        gridLineColor: '#E4E7ED',
        numLines: 6,
        gridtextSize: 14,
        lineWidth: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        lineColors: ['#00B5B8', '#FA8E57', '#F25E75'],
        data:arrData
    });
```

My controller to count the number of new students registered and the number of online students per month

```php
class DashboardController extends AdminBaseController
{
    public function index () 
    {
       $month = 1;
        $studNew = [];
        $studOnline = [];
        $studActive = [];
        for($i = $month; $i < 13; $i++) {
        //count new students
        $newStudents = Member::where('member_type_id',1)->whereMonth('created_at', $i)->get();
        $studNew[$i] = $newStudents->count(); 

        //students online
        $onlStudents = Member::where('member_type_id',1)->whereMonth('updated_at', $i)->get();
        $studOnline[$i] = $onlStudents->count(); 

        // count card active
        $act = Order::where('status', "active")->whereMonth('updated_at', $i)->get();
        $studActive[$i] = $act->count(); 
        }

        $monthNewStudent = json_encode($studNew);
        $monthOnline = json_encode($studOnline);
        $monthActive = json_encode($studActive);
        return view('admin.dashboard.index', compact('monthNewStudent',
                                                    'monthOnline',
                                                    'monthActive'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your PHP code

Comment: @CaddyDz it's updated

Comment: Make an Ajax Request from your js script and ask about those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set values in a variable and then can pass that variable to view. At view, you can use that variable like below:

```
{!! $yourvariable !!}
```

So in your case, it will be like this:

```
data: {!! $yourvariable !!},
```

Hope it helps you!!